# Oracle apex Gantt chart how to highlight weekends

Tags: oracle-apex, gantt-chart, jet

I have created a gantt chart on oracle apex. I need to highlight the weekends similar to what we have on jet. can someone please help me with this.
Thanks in advance.

I have gone through the oracle jet code. Please refer to below link. It highlights all weekends. but am not able to use it on apex.
https://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/jet/jetCookbook.html?component=gantt&demo=multipleTasks

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use Javascript here.
Find out the weekends through javascript. Use ID oj-gantt-minor-axis-label to make change using javascript initialization code for apex chart